# Mongodb Query for $lookup against string id in local & _id in foreign table

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb version: MongoDB shell version v3.6.6

I've data in two collections as follows:

1. collection event:

   `{
       "_id" : ObjectId("5b52dc2a9f5ac63b61186f45"),
       "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-07-21T07:09:30.575Z"),
       "UserEvent" : "User disconnected user_id=5b522eda9f5ac65b111c72fb",
       "Event" : "User disconnected ",
       "UserId" : "5b522eda9f5ac65b111c72fb"
   }`
2. collection users:

   `{
       "_id" : ObjectId("5b522eda9f5ac65b111c72fb"),
       "name" : "som",
       "role" : "1"
   }`

   I need result as :

   `{
       "_id" : ObjectId("5b52dc2a9f5ac63b61186f45"),
       "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-07-21T07:09:30.575Z"),
       "UserEvent" : "User disconnected user_id=5b522eda9f5ac65b111c72fb",
       "Event" : "User disconnected ",
       "UserId" : "5b522eda9f5ac65b111c72fb",
       "name" : "som"
   }`

   Please note, element name from users collection.
   I used $lookup combinations several ways but doesn't yield the result because of _id & string UserId joining issues i believe. I'll be thankful if I can get any help.

basically i want to accomplish a simple join as follows:
    
    `Select e.*, u.name
      from event e,
           users u
      where e.UserId = u._id`


Note: e.UserId has only string like "5b522eda9f5ac65b111c72fb" but u._id has ObjectId("5b522eda9f5ac65b111c72fb")

Comment: You can use [`$toObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/#exp._S_toObjectId) to do this in 4.0, but you're probably better off storing `UserId` as an ObjectId in your event collection regardless as it's more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Johnny! I had tried using all those functions but din't worked. Actually i was using mongodb 3.6, $toObjectId  & toString() is not supported there. After i upgraded to 4.0, now voila alls great. Thanks for your reply.